# How to correctly subscribe to Changed sequence of ReactiveObject?

Tags: linq, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

Another question about ReactiveUi. I have a ViewModel for an edit form. Model is ReactiveObject. I want to enable savecommand only when changes of object was take place. My try:

```
var canSaveCommand =
        this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.CurrentClient)
            .Where(client => client != null)
            .Select(client =>
                client.Changed
            )
            .Any();
```

But when the form appears the `SaveCommand` is already enabled. Where my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [Switch](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html) not SelectMany. SelectMany will not unsubscribe from the previous client. It will merge events from all clients. Switch unsubscribes from the previous client before it subscribes to the next.

```
 var canSaveCommand =
            this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.CurrentClient)
                .Where(client => client != null)
                .Select(client =>
                    client.Changed
                )
                .Switch()
                .Any();
```

For example the following code makes it clear. Let's say we have a class called `AudioChannel` It generates audio frames we can can process and send to the speaker.

```
 public class IAudioChannel {
     public IObservable<AudioFrame> AudioFrameObservable {get;} 
 }
```

Then we might have a list of audio nodes that the user can select but we only want the most current sending audio to the speaker. The below class makes available the currently selected audio node as an observable.

```
public class AudioListViewModel {
    public class IObservable<IAudioChannel> CurrentAudioChannelObservable {get;}

}
```

Now consider the following code

```
AudioListViewModel viewModel;

viewModel
    .CurrentAudioChannelObservable
    .SelectMany(current=>current.AudioFrameObservable)
    .Subscribe(frame=>frame.Play());
```

vs

```
AudioListViewModel viewModel;

viewModel
    .CurrentAudioChannelObservable
    .Select(current=>current.AudioFrameObservable)
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(frame=>frame.Play());
```

In the first version as we change the selection of audio nodes we add more and more subscriptions. The audio output quickly becomes a garbled mess of mixed channels. In the second version only one channel is subscribed to at a time and the audio output only plays the output from a single channel.

Many people make this mistake when starting out with RX. For example I found a [bug in the ReactiveUI framework](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/253) that used SelectMany instead of Switch.

## However

There is a built in way within ReactiveUI to achieve this in a clear way

There is actually another way to achieve what you want and I will put it in another answer just to show you how to use ReactiveUI.

```
var canSaveCommand =
        this
          .WhenAnyObservable(vm => vm.CurrentClient.Changed)
          .StartWith(false);
```

Note that null doesn't have to be explicity handled though you should start with **false** to make sure a value exists when no observable is available to start with.

[WhenAnyObservable](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/when-any/)

> WhenAnyObservable acts a lot like the Rx operator CombineLatest, in
>   that it watches one or multiple observables and allows you to define a
>   projection based on the latest value from each. WhenAnyObservable
>   differs from CombineLatest in that its parameters are expressions,
>   rather than direct references to the target observables. The impact of
>   this difference is that the watch set up by WhenAnyObservable is not
>   tied to the specific observable instances present at the time of
>   subscription. That is, **the observable pointed to by the expression can
>   be replaced later**, and the results of the new observable will still be
>   captured. An example of where this can come in handy is when a view
>   wants to observe an observable on a viewmodel, but the viewmodel can
>   be replaced during the view's lifetime. Rather than needing to
>   resubscribe to the target observable after every change of viewmodel,
>   you can use WhenAnyObservable to specify the 'path' to watch. This
>   allows you to use a single subscription in the view, regardless of the
>   life of the target viewmodel.

Comment: Problem what Changed is standart event wraper -
 IObservable<IReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<IReactiveObject>> and need convert to bool. In my case, I finally added another observable property in VM HasChanges and set in subscriptions of any().

Comment: P.S. ReactiveUI looks great foer WPF, but it has many pitfalls, and implicit singularity. Sometimes I want to spit and leave him. :)

Comment: "Implicit singularity" ??

Comment: ...implicit peculiarity/features.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean sorry. Could you please give an example.

Comment: This is not working since .Changed does not return a boolean value but an IObservable<IReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<IReactiveObject>> itself.

Comment: It works exactly *because* Changed returns an Observable and WhenAnyObservable accepts a *path* to an Observable. If you want something that works for a path to a Boolean just use *WhenAny*

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your Select to a SelectMany. That will then give you an Observable of the changes to be passed into Any instead of an Observable of an Observable of the changes to be passed into Any.

Comment: SelectMany will not unsubscribe from the previous client. It will merge events from all clients and cause you some nasty bugs.

Comment: A Take(1) After the Where would soon fix that, assuming however that the user has a scenario where CurrentClient changes numerous times which in many scenarios isn't the case.

Comment: If you are explicit that only one value can be available then it is better to use ``Task<T>`` ie provide a method ``Task<Client> GetClientAsync()``. With properties it is safer to assume they can always change and if they don't in ``v1`` of the software then in ``v9`` they might and your assumption will burn you.